# Combining multiple queries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a bit of a long-winded question, and I apologize for that. My SQL skills are severely lacking (something I'd like to redress ASAP). As a result, I really cannot fathom how I can tackle this problem that I have run into.

Basically, our project is storing user notifications in a single table `notifications`. The table structure looks like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+----------------+------------+
|  user_id  |  subject  |     action     |     date   |
+-----------+-----------+----------------+------------+
|     1     |     2     | started_follow | 1371034287 |
|     1     |     2     | stopped_follow | 1371034287 |
|     2     |     5     |   added_item   | 1371034287 |
+-----------+-----------+----------------+------------+
```

`user_id` always contains the ID of the user that performed the action, and `date` is obviously the date that the notification was registered. The tricky part is that `subject` is a reference to an ID of another table, and that table is largely dependent upon the value of the `action` column.

So for example, in the first two records of the sample data, `subject` is a reference to an ID in the `users` table (i.e. the user who was followed, and then unfollowed). In the third record, `subject` is a reference to an ID in the `items` table.

We also need to perform several `JOIN` statements, depending upon the condition of `action`. So, if it's `added_item` for example, we need to `JOIN` several other tables (to check for settings and other requirements).

I came across a legacy function in the code which essentially checks to see how many notifications exist in the table for a given user since a specified date. The previous developer has simply used a series of queries, and then returned the total number of several `SELECT COUNT(*)` statements as follows (please note, this is all inside the PHP `User` class):

```
// Get the number of notifications since the specified time (or of all time):
public function countNotifications($since = '')
{
    $sinceString = ($since == '') ? '' : "AND `date` > '$since'";

    // Notifications when someone follows $this:
    $started_following = $this->_database->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`
                                                  FROM `notifications`
                                                  WHERE `action` = 'started_following'
                                                    AND `subject` = '{$this->id}'
                                                    $sinceString
                                                    AND `notifications`.`user_id` != '{$this->id}'")->fetchObject();

    // Notifications when someone stops following $this:
    $stopped_following = $this->_database->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`
                                                  FROM `notifications`
                                                  WHERE `action` = 'stopped_following'
                                                    AND `subject` = '{$this->id}'
                                                    $sinceString
                                                    AND `notifications`.`user_id` != '{$this->id}'")->fetchObject();

    // Notifications when someone sends $this a message:
    $sent_message = $this->_database->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`
                                             FROM `notifications`
                                             WHERE `action` = 'sent_message'
                                               AND `subject` = '{$this->id}'
                                               $sinceString
                                               AND `notifications`.`user_id` != '{$this->id}'")->fetchObject();

    // Notifications when someone favorites $this' items:
    $favorited_item = $this->_database->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`
                                               FROM `notifications`
                                               INNER JOIN `items` ON `notifications`.`subject` = `items`.`id`
                                               INNER JOIN `categories` ON `items`.`category` = `categories`.`id`
                                               WHERE `notifications`.`action` = 'favorited_item'
                                                 AND `categories`.`owner` = '{$this->id}'
                                                 $sinceString
                                                 AND `notifications`.`user_id` != '{$this->id}'")->fetchObject();

    // Notifications when someone adds a comment to $this' items:
    $comments = $this->_database->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`
                                         FROM `notifications`
                                         INNER JOIN `items` ON `notifications`.`subject` = `items`.`id`
                                         INNER JOIN `categories` ON `items`.`category` = `categories`.`id`
                                         WHERE `notifications`.`action` = 'added_comment'
                                           AND `categories`.`owner` = '{$this->id}'
                                           $sinceString
                                           AND `notifications`.`user_id` != '{$this->id}'")->fetchObject();

    // Notifications when a follower of $this adds a new item:
    $new_items = $this->_database->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total`
                                         FROM `notifications`
                                         INNER JOIN `categories` ON `notifications`.`subject` = `categories`.`id`
                                         INNER JOIN (SELECT `followee` FROM `user_followers` WHERE `follower` = '{$this->id}') `followers`
                                         WHERE `notifications`.`action` = 'added_item'
                                           AND `followee` = `user_id`
                                           $sinceString
                                           AND `user_id` !=  '{$this->id}'")->fetchObject();

    // Notifications when a follower of $this adds a new collection:
    $new_collections = $this->_database->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total`
                                                FROM `notifications`
                                                INNER JOIN `categories` ON `notifications`.`subject` = `categories`.`id`
                                                INNER JOIN (SELECT `followee` FROM `user_followers` WHERE `follower` = '{$this->id}') `followers`
                                                WHERE `notifications`.`action` = 'added-collection'
                                                   AND `followee` = `user_id`
                                                   $sinceString
                                                   AND `user_id` !=  '{$this->id}'")->fetchObject();

    // Notifications when a follower of $this adds a new category:
    $new_categories = $this->_database->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total`
                                               FROM `notifications`
                                               INNER JOIN  `categories` ON `notifications`.`subject` =  `categories`.`id`
                                               INNER JOIN (SELECT `followee` FROM `user_followers` WHERE `follower` = '{$this->id}') `followers`
                                               WHERE `notifications`.`action` =  'added-category'
                                                 AND `followee` = `user_id`
                                                 $sinceString
                                                 AND `user_id` !=  '{$this->id}'")->fetchObject();

    // Selling Notifications:
    // Notifications when someone makes an offer for an item $this is selling:
    $offers = $this->_database->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`
                                       FROM `notifications`
                                       INNER JOIN `items` ON `notifications`.`subject` = `items`.`id`
                                       INNER JOIN `categories` ON `items`.`category` = `categories`.`id`
                                       WHERE `notifications`.`action` = 'made_offer'
                                         AND `categories`.`owner` = '{$this->id}'
                                         $sinceString
                                         AND `notifications`.`user_id` != '{$this->id}'")->fetchObject();

    // Notifications when someone purchases an item $this is selling:
    $purchases = $this->_database->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`
                                          FROM `notifications`
                                          INNER JOIN `items` ON `notifications`.`subject` = `items`.`id`
                                          INNER JOIN `categories` ON `items`.`category` = `categories`.`id`
                                          INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`, `item_id`
                                                      FROM `user_favorite_items`
                                                      WHERE `user_id` = '{$this->id}') `following` ON `items`.`id` = `following`.`item_id`
                                          WHERE `notifications`.`action` = 'bought_item'
                                            AND `following`.`count` = 1
                                            AND `categories`.`owner` = '{$this->id}'
                                            $sinceString
                                            AND `notifications`.`user_id` != '{$this->id}'")->fetchObject();

    // Notifications when an item that $this favorited is listed for sale:
    $item_sales = $this->_database->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`
                                           FROM `notifications`
                                           INNER JOIN `items` ON `notifications`.`subject` = `items`.`id`
                                           INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`, `item_id`
                                                       FROM `user_favorite_items`
                                                       WHERE `user_id` = '{$this->id}'
                                                    ) `following` ON `items`.`id` = `following`.`item_id`
                                           WHERE `notifications`.`action` = 'selling_item'
                                             AND `following`.`count` = 1
                                             $sinceString
                                             AND `notifications`.`user_id` != '{$this->id}'")->fetchObject();

    // Return the counts:
    return ($started_following->count + 
            $stopped_following->count +
            $sent_message->count +
            $favorited_item->count +
            $comments->count +
            $new_items->count +
            $new_collections->count +
            $new_categories->count +
            $offers->count +
            $purchases->count +
            $item_sales->count);
}
```

While this does the job perfectly well, it makes it extremely difficult to fetch all records from a specified date, for example, or all records that relate to a specific User ID.

I suppose my question really is what is the best way to combine the numerous SQL statements provided? I have experimented with `LEFT JOIN`, but as you can see we need to join the table to a different column, depending upon the value of `notifications`.`action`. While I can do this using table aliases, it does tend to return a **lot** of redundant data.

Essentially, I'd like to combine the `COUNT(*)` queries given above so that we can simply return all `notifications.*` for a given User ID and / or time period.

I'd also like to avoid using `UNION` if at all possible (for obvious reasons).

Sorry for the lengthy question, but I've tried to make everything as clear as possible. Before anyone asks, I'm unable to change the structure of the data or the DB schema, as this is for an existing site.

I have put together an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05527/2) to make things a little more clear.

Comment: Excellent question setup, but just to verify, you are looking to combine all of the queries listed above into one massive query? Basically you want to eliminate the complex return statement? Or are you needing new/more queries to handle things like fetch records w/in a specific date or records related to a specific user ID?

Comment: Well, both I suppose. My thinking was, that if the combined `COUNT(*)` query worked, it would work just as well for fetching information within a specific date. Basically, I want to be able to return `notifications.*` for a specified user ID within a given time period, or of all time. Does that make sense?

Comment: I have edited the question to give a little more background information and more info on what I'd like to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those queries vary in complexity and what they are doing.

The first 3 could be combined into a single query returning (up to) 3 rows:-

```
SELECT action, COUNT(*) AS `count`
  FROM `notifications`
  WHERE `action` IN ( 'started_following', 'stopped_following', 'sent_message')
    AND `subject` = '{$this->id}'
    $sinceString
    AND `notifications`.`user_id` != '{$this->id}'
GROUP BY action
```

To force that to return 3 rows you could possibly do something like this:-

```
SELECT WantedActions.WantedAction, COUNT(*) AS `count`
  FROM (SELECT 'started_following' AS WantedAction UNION SELECT 'stopped_following' UNION SELECT 'sent_message') AS WantedActions
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `notifications`
  ON WantedActions.WantedAction = notifications.action
  WHERE `subject` = '{$this->id}'
    $sinceString
    AND `notifications`.`user_id` != '{$this->id}'
GROUP BY WantedActions.WantedAction
```

You can probably do similar things for others

EDIT

```
SELECT started_following, stopped_following, sent_message, favorited_item, comments, new_items, new_collections, new_categories, offers, purchases, item_sales
FROM (SELECT SUM(IF(`action` = 'started_following', 1, 0) AS started_following, 
                    SUM(IF(`action` = 'stopped_following', 1, 0) AS stopped_following, 
                    SUM(IF(`action` = 'sent_message', 1, 0) AS sent_message
            FROM `notifications`
            WHERE `subject` = '{$this->id}'
            $sinceString
            AND `notifications`.`user_id` != '{$this->id}') Sub1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(IF(`action` = 'favorited_item', 1, 0) AS favorited_item, 
                    SUM(IF(`action` = 'added_comment', 1, 0) AS comments, 
                    SUM(IF(`action` = 'made_offer', 1, 0) AS offers
            FROM `notifications`
            INNER JOIN `items` ON `notifications`.`subject` = `items`.`id`
            INNER JOIN `categories` ON `items`.`category` = `categories`.`id`
            WHERE `categories`.`owner` = '{$this->id}'
            $sinceString
            AND `notifications`.`user_id` != '{$this->id}') Sub2
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(IF(`action` = 'added_item', 1, 0) AS new_items, 
                    SUM(IF(`action` = 'added-collection', 1, 0) AS new_collections, 
                    SUM(IF(`action` = 'added-category', 1, 0) AS new_categories
            FROM `notifications`
            INNER JOIN `categories` ON `notifications`.`subject` = `categories`.`id`
            INNER JOIN (SELECT `followee` FROM `user_followers` WHERE `follower` = '{$this->id}') `followers`
            WHERE `followee` = `user_id`
            $sinceString
            AND `user_id` !=  '{$this->id}') Sub3
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS purchases
          FROM `notifications`
          INNER JOIN `items` ON `notifications`.`subject` = `items`.`id`
          INNER JOIN `categories` ON `items`.`category` = `categories`.`id`
          INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`, `item_id`
                      FROM `user_favorite_items`
                      WHERE `user_id` = '{$this->id}'
                    ) `following` ON `items`.`id` = `following`.`item_id`
          WHERE `notifications`.`action` = 'bought_item'
            AND `following`.`count` = 1
            AND `categories`.`owner` = '{$this->id}'
            $sinceString
            AND `notifications`.`user_id` != '{$this->id}') Sub4
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS item_sales
           FROM `notifications`
           INNER JOIN `items` ON `notifications`.`subject` = `items`.`id`
           INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`, `item_id`
                       FROM `user_favorite_items`
                       WHERE `user_id` = '{$this->id}'
                    ) `following` ON `items`.`id` = `following`.`item_id`
           WHERE `notifications`.`action` = 'selling_item'
             AND `following`.`count` = 1
             $sinceString
             AND `notifications`.`user_id` != '{$this->id}') Sub5
```

EDIT - Using a union

```
SELECT action, COUNT(*)  AS action_count
            FROM `notifications`
            WHERE `subject` = '{$this->id}'
            AND action IN ('started_following', 'stopped_following', 'sent_message')
            $sinceString
            AND `notifications`.`user_id` != '{$this->id}'
            GROUP BY action
UNION
SELECT action, COUNT(*)  AS action_count
            FROM `notifications`
            INNER JOIN `items` ON `notifications`.`subject` = `items`.`id`
            INNER JOIN `categories` ON `items`.`category` = `categories`.`id`
            WHERE `categories`.`owner` = '{$this->id}'
            AND action IN ('favorited_item', 'added_comment', 'made_offer')
            $sinceString
            AND `notifications`.`user_id` != '{$this->id}'
            GROUP BY action
UNION
SELECT action, COUNT(*)  AS action_count
            FROM `notifications`
            INNER JOIN `categories` ON `notifications`.`subject` = `categories`.`id`
            INNER JOIN (SELECT `followee` FROM `user_followers` WHERE `follower` = '{$this->id}') `followers`
            WHERE `followee` = `user_id`
            AND action IN ('added_item', 'added-collection', 'added-category')
            $sinceString
            AND `user_id` !=  '{$this->id}'
            GROUP BY action
UNION
SELECT 'purchases' AS action, COUNT(*)  AS action_count
          FROM `notifications`
          INNER JOIN `items` ON `notifications`.`subject` = `items`.`id`
          INNER JOIN `categories` ON `items`.`category` = `categories`.`id`
           INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS `count`, `item_id`
                       FROM `user_favorite_items`
                       GROUP BY `user_id`, item_id
                    ) `following` ON `items`.`id` = `following`.`item_id` AND `notifications`.`user_id` = `following`.`user_id`
          WHERE `notifications`.`action` = 'bought_item'
            AND `following`.`count` = 1
            AND `categories`.`owner` = '{$this->id}'
            $sinceString
            AND `notifications`.`user_id` != '{$this->id}'
UNION
SELECT 'item_sales' AS action, COUNT(*) AS action_count
           FROM `notifications`
           INNER JOIN `items` ON `notifications`.`subject` = `items`.`id`
           INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS `count`, `item_id`
                       FROM `user_favorite_items`
                       GROUP BY `user_id`, item_id
                    ) `following` ON `items`.`id` = `following`.`item_id` AND `notifications`.`user_id` = `following`.`user_id`
           WHERE `notifications`.`action` = 'selling_item'
             AND `following`.`count` = 1
             $sinceString
             AND `notifications`.`user_id` != '{$this->id}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. As I said though, I'd rather not use `UNION` (performance reasons amongst others). In addition, I'm sure this can be achieved by using conditional joins, but I don't have a great working knowledge of them. I know the first three could easily be combined, but would like to do as much of this on the SQL server as possible, while avoiding duplicate data and so forth.

Comment: UNION shouldn't really cause a performance issue (for some things it is the best solution to allowing MySQL to use decent indexes). The counts are all fairly separate so difficult to clean up. I have knocked up a query which I am updating my answer with but don't think it will be that efficient.

Comment: Thanks for your help, and the detailed second query. It isn't overly efficient with the real data set. I did some benchmarking with `UNION` and it seems that perhaps this is indeed the way forward. My problem now (being someone SQL-illiterate) is to create a unioned query that can return all notifications for a specific user within a given time period. Would you be able to point me in the direction of something like that? Once again, I really appreciate your efforts here - SQL gives me a severe headache...!

Comment: All notifications are easy, the problem is that the queries you have there are limiting the results in different ways depending on which notifications are required. I have knocked up another query using UNIONs (not tested I am afraid) which I hope will help

Comment: Thank you for your great help. I was actually working on a similar query, and think I have cracked it > http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05527/3

Comment: Biggest performance problem you will have is that those tables have few useful indexes. For example every query has the notifications table checking for the user id, but the notifications table doesn't have an index on user id.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I don't know any way to combat that, with the current structure though :(

Comment: Can you not just add the indexes required?

Comment: Surely adding an index for `users.id` on `subject` only solves part of the problem, since the `subject` can also relate to other PKs in other tables?

Comment: MySQL can choose which index to use on each table. Note that it can only use a single index per table in a query, but for this a pair of UNIONed queries are treated as 2 different queries and each can use a different index. Also you can have an index over multiple columns (so you could add an index on notifications that covered bother the user_id and subject fields - and if done in that order it would be used for checks against user_id alone as well)

Comment: Thanks for your continued help on this. So if I use `ALTER TABLE notifications ADD INDEX (action, subject);`, we're good to go? Sorry if this is a basic question. I am ruing the day the DBA left this project...

Comment: Yes, although probably worth adding it as (user_id, action, subject)

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to specify the external reference, or just the index itself?

Comment: If by external reference you mean the table they refer to (ie, foreign key relationship) then this isn't necessary (or possible depending on the database engine in use).